# How to redirect to another page and call a Function there on Angular ng-click

Tags: javascript, php, html, angularjs

I have a page where I toggle between areas using angular functions onclick at home.php like

```
<button class="btn btn-success btn-lg span6" ng-click="settingManage('setup-guide')" ><i class="fa fa-cogs"></i>  Guide</button>
<button class="btn btn-info btn-lg span6" ng-click="settingManage('setup-boxes')" ><i class="fa fa-cogs"></i> Manage</button>
```

And I show their relative content with:

```
<div class="wizard" ng-if="mainPage == 'setup-guide'">
Guide Content
</div>
```

And

```
<div class="setup-area" ng-if="mainPage == 'setup-boxes'">
Manage Content
</div>
```

This is working fine but the problem I am having is to navigate back from another PHP page to a specific home.php area e.g page2.php to home.php and directly showing the content of say 'setup-guide' content. So, to navigate from page2.php to home.php and call `settingManage('setup-guide')`

Any idea how this can be achieved?

page2.php has angular enabled and have same angular's js file as home.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can append a query string to your home.php url in page2.php:

```
<a href="home.php?setting=setup">home</a>
```

then, on home.php, there should be a script to detect this query string, and perform an action if present:

```
if (window.location.indexOf('setting') != -1) {
   settingManage('setup-guide');
}
```